# How to overcome [cabal: error while loading shared libraries:] error on arch linux?

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, archlinux, cabal-install

I had some problems a while back trying to use cabal, so I reinstalled ghc (from 8.6.3) to 8.6.4.

When I try to use cabal (after it is uninstalled completely) I still get the below error, but can't see the file mentioned in when using fzf from the root directory.   [image: fzf from root]

```
[warrick@warrick-pc ~]$ cabal
cabal: error while loading shared libraries: libHSzip-archive-0.3.3-FtEZ8cVpsWW1rhccfBNhic-ghc8.6.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have completely removed ~/.cabal but still don't have any clue how cabal is still being called from somewhere even though I have unistalled it.  If I reinstall it and use cabal I get the same error message.

Comment: I don't quite understand, is your problem that you can't remove cabal properly? (In which case, isn't there a command like `type -a cabal` that shows where the executable resides?)

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problems and ended up reinstalling the specific Haskell libraries. E.g, for `libHSdlist-0.8.0.6-CQRMCGRgL5B3ZxhntX4iOr-ghc8.6.4.so` I'd run `pacman -S haskell-dlist`. So in your case, you'd want to run `pacman -S haskell-zip-archive`

Answer (score 1):

I had a related error but with pandoc. I installed it using `yay -S pandoc` and when I removed and reinstalled it using `pacman -S pandoc` the error disappeared.